# How to fix the array index out of bound in java?

Tags: java

I have a problem of this following java code it returns array index out of bound. Can anyone help me in this problem.

```
public static double calculateMedian(int[] arr) {

    int[] sortedArr = bubbleSort(arr); //this code returns ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException 
}

public static int[] bubbleSort(int[] arr) {
    boolean performedSwap = true;
    int tempValue = 0;

    while(performedSwap) {
        performedSwap = false;

        for (int i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] > arr[i+1]) {
            tempValue = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[i+1];
            arr[i+1] = tempValue;

            performedSwap = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

The output above java code:

```
C:\Users\root\Java>java Median_Methods
How many numbers will you input?
2
Input the 1st number:
1
Input the 2nd number:
4
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
at Median_Methods.calculateMedian(Median_Methods.java:58)
```

Comment: Posted code won't compile, so your output doesn't match your post.

Comment: You are looping until less than the length but then you are calling the index + 1. Since you are looking one ahead you only have to loop until `i < arr.length-1`

Comment: Downvote because this question is answered in different questions. Before asking try to search and compare your code to the solutions provided on the other questions on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `arr.Length` has an excess value or null value. So in order to not step on that null value you should `-1` your `arr.Length` inside your looping.

```
for (int i=0; i < arr.length -1; i++) {
            if (arr[i] > arr[i+1]) {
            tempValue = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[i+1];
            arr[i+1] = tempValue;

            performedSwap = true;
            }
        }
```